# Directions for a Canaanite

Tags: noachide-laws, olam-haba-world-to-come, canaan, noahide

Can a member of the Canaanites expect to be among the righteous? What must he do to stand in such a position?

Comment: I don't think Canaanites exist today. Do you mean theoretically?

Comment: I do not have time to develop the answer at the moment but it seems to me the starting point is Mishneh Torah Hilchos Melahim u'Milchamotehim chapter 6 (and its sources) and my recollection and cursory review suggests that the Canaanites were required to be given the option to observe the Sheva Mitzvos b'nei Noach.

Comment: According to רש"י, אליעזר עבד אברהם was a כנעני.